# how to assign "contents-directory" in spec file of pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

In the document of Pyinstaller, it says set "contents-directory" to "." to re-enable old onedir layout without contents directory. Where to set this parameter in spec file?

Answer (score 0):

In your .spec file, under the 'exe' option, add the `contents_directory='.'`.

The basic exe section of your .spec file will look like this.

```
exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    contents_directory='.',
)
```